# Adding gmap markers programmatically with a module

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7

I've been researching how to add markers to a drupal 7 gmap for more hours than I feel comfortable admitting. The reason I have to do it through a module and not views is because of client specifications that I won't go into here. The code below is what I have so far, everything I've found seems to point in this direction and it looks right to me. But when I go to the page, no markers show on the map. Can anyone help me out here?

This uses the gmaps module for drupal 7 btw.

```
function rrs_custom_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['search-by-towns'] = array(
    'title' => 'Search by Towns',
    'page callback' => 'search_by_towns',
    'access arguments'  => array('access content'),
    'type'  => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

return $items;
}
function search_by_towns() {
$query = "SELECT node.title AS node_title, location.lid AS location_lid, location.latitude AS gmap_lat, location.longitude AS gmap_lon, location.name as loc_name, location.street, location.city, location.province, location.postal_code, gmap_taxonomy_node.marker AS gmap_node_marker, taxonomy_term_data.tid AS tid, taxonomy_term_data.vid AS vid, gmap_taxonomy_term.marker AS marker
    FROM 
    {node} node
    LEFT JOIN {location_instance} location_instance ON node.vid = location_instance.vid
    LEFT JOIN {location} location ON location_instance.lid = location.lid
    LEFT JOIN {gmap_taxonomy_node} gmap_taxonomy_node ON node.vid = gmap_taxonomy_node.vid
    INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index ON node.nid = taxonomy_index.nid
    INNER JOIN {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data ON taxonomy_index.tid = taxonomy_term_data.tid
    LEFT JOIN {gmap_taxonomy_term} gmap_taxonomy_term ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = gmap_taxonomy_term.tid
    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('listing', 'town')) AND (taxonomy_term_data.vid = '3') ))
    ORDER BY tid desc";

    $javascript = drupal_add_js();
    $result = db_query($query);
    $marker = array();

    foreach ($result as $res) {
        $text = '<div class="location vcard"> <div class="adr"> <span class="fn">'.$res->loc_name.'</span> <div class="street-address"> '.$res->street.' </div> <span class="locality">'.$res->city.'</span>, <span class="region">'.$res->province.'</span> <span class="postal-code">'.$res->postal_code.'</span> </div> <div class="map-link"> <div class="location map-link">See map: <a href="http://maps.google.com?q='.$res->gmap_lat.'+'.$res->gmap_lon.'">Google Maps</a></div> </div> </div>';

        $marker[] = array(
            'latitude' => $res->gmap_lat,
            'longitude' => $res->gmap_lon,
            'markername' => $res->marker,
            'offset' => 0,
            'text' => $text,
            'opts' => array(
                'title' => '',
                'highlight' => 0,
                'highlightcolor' => '#FF0000'
            )
        );
    }

    $map_array = array(
        'id' => "auto1map",         // id attribute for the map
        'width' => "685px",        // map width in pixels or %
        'height' => "480px",      // map height in pixels
        'latitude' => '36.10237644873644',    // map center latitude
        'longitude' => '-80.8758544921875',  // map center longitude
        'zoom' => 8,              // zoom level
        'maptype' => "Map",       // baselayer type
        'controltype' => "Small"  // size of map controls
    );
    $map_array['markers'] = $marker;

  $output = theme('gmap', array(
      'element' => array(
        '#type' => 'gmap',
          '#gmap_settings' => $map_array,
          '#input'  => FALSE,
          '#theme'  => 'gmap',
          '#children'   => '',
          )
        )
    );

return $output; 
}
```